# OpenId Connect library from Vue app to OpenId provider

Tags: javascript, vue.js, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to build a Single Page Application using vue(client) and Java Spring REST APIs(backend). I need to secure them using OpenId Connect. The OpenId provider is RapidIdentity. This provider does not have a library similar to the one provided by others(eg: Okta, Auth0). 
I can use Spring Security on the API side to verify the tokens. 
I am looking for a library to connect from Vue side to the provider to authenticate and fetch tokens from provider.
Can someone please suggest a good library to connect from vue application to the open id provider.
So far I have looked at Auth0 library. I am not sure if I can use Auth0 with RapidIdentity.

Comment: Well, Can you share the link of RapidIdentity & other relevant links?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generic OIDC client library, such as [oidc-client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki#usermanager) or [AppAuth-JS](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-JS). I'm sure there are many others as well. You could do a search for "OpenID connect client" or "OpenID connect javascript."

There is an example VueJS app that uses oidc-client [here](https://github.com/joaojosefilho/vuejsOidcClient).

I can't find anything about RapidIdentity, but they should provide you with the settings that can use to configure whichever OIDC client library you will be using. [These](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki#required-settings) are the required settings for oidc-client, for example.

Comment: This oidc-clent is now archived. So need to migrate to the openId connect since they depricated the openId auth.  AppAuth-JS. - https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-JS  &  OpenId Connect Playground - https://openidconnect.net/